# Java non-blocking IO: Is it possible to check how much you can write before calling channel.write()?

Tags: java, sockets, real-time, nio, nonblocking

I understand a channel.write(outBuffer) can fail to write all the contents of outBuffer because the underlying socket buffer is full. Then you have to register OP_WRITE and wait for selector callbacks. However I don't want to write a partial message and I would like to wait until the channel.write operation is capable of writing out my full message. Is that possible or I have to write to find out how much I can write?

---

Talking about a http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/WritableByteChannel.html of course.

Comment: What kind of channel are you talking about?  Channel itself only has `isOpen` and `close` methods: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Comment: @chrisapotek - Since NIO is used in Java to refer to the "New IO" packages in java.nio, changed the title to "non-blocking IO", per your comments in my answer, which I'm now deleting.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it. There is no such thing as a 'message' in TCP. TCP may break your write up any way it likes, and the receiver may receive it in one read or N or anything in between.